# Why static member cannot be accessed in a property method but ok in prototype method?

Tags: typescript

Can someone help me understand why is it an error to access a static member from a property method an in Typescript? It works ok in plain ES6 and as a proper prototype method.

```
class FooBar {
    static v = 123;

    static foo = () => this.v;  // this is an error in TS (but ok in ES6)

    static bar() {
        return this.v;  // but this is ok in TS??
    }
}
```

This is the error, it seems to consider the code in the function body as the property initializer itself:

```
apptest2.ts:40:24 - error TS2334: 'this' cannot be referenced in a static property initializer.

40     static foo = () => this.v;
                          ~~~~
```

The error would make sense if the code was more like `static foo = this.v`, but being part of the function callback does not make sense to consider this as part of the initialization phase of the class, where `this` could not be defined... anyway, that also works in `ES6` which adds to my confusion on why this is an error and why it works in `bar()` but not in `foo()`.

Comment: @ritaj it refers to the class itself.

Answer (score 7):

I had this issue come up today and I noticed the following:

if you are using arrow functions you need to reference the `ClassName` rather than `this`

```js
class FooBar {
    static v = 123;
    static fooArrow = () => FooBar.v; //works
    static foo () {this.v}; //works
}
```

It seems this is a known issue in Typescript, and there have been [long term discussions on a possible fix](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36267). I think it's a good idea to steer clear of arrow functions in Classes for the moment due to issues around how the `this` context is bound.